# how to type sigma symbol?

Tags: symbols

I do not know hoe to type this sigma symbol [image] in latex. Anyone has idea?

Comment: This is not a sigma, but a capital Fraktur S: `\usepackage{amssymb}` and `\mathfrak{S}`.

Comment: This might help you for the future : http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: Do you need to typeset this symbol (Fraktur-S) in math mode or text mode?